# Need to use EWS (Exchange Web Service) to receive Microsoft exchange's/Outlook emails in java spring boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to connect to Microsoft exchange server(EWS) with the help of EWS API provided by Microsoft.
The Spring boot application should be a continuous listener, so that the application should be able to listen all the new emails which are getting received in the outlook.

I have written a REST API to connect exchange server from java spring boot project. Created required EWS object and subscribed to the new Email notification so that it listen the new email.

Code template:

Added dependency in pom as :

`<dependency>`

`<groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>`

`<artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>`

`<version>2.0</version>`

`</dependency>`

Java controller :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/EWSImplementation") 
public Object ewsImplementation() { 

try { 

String userName = "userName"; 
String password = "password";
String serverAddress = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/exchange.asmx";

ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);
exService.setCredentials(credentials);
URI uri = new URI(serverAddress);
exService.setUrl(uri);
exService.setTraceEnabled(true);

PullSubscription subscription = exService.subscribeToPullNotificationsOnAllFolders(500, null,
        EventType.NewMail);

GetEventsResults events = subscription.getEvents();

for (ItemEvent itemEvent : events.getItemEvents()) {
    Item item = Item.bind(exService, itemEvent.getItemId());
    log.info("New email received: {}", item.getSubject());
}
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

The user name and password which I have used here are working in the outlook i.e. we are receiving emails in the outlook.

When I am calling this API, it is giving error as,

2023-05-04T12:39:27.304+05:30  INFO 272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-04T12:39:27.304+05:30  INFO 272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-04T12:39:27.306+05:30  INFO 272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.subscribeToPullNotificationsOnAllFolders(ExchangeService.java:1847)
at com.nib.plp.controller.FileOperationsController.ewsImplementation(FileOperationsController.java:111)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:644)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:62)
... 53 more
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.http.HttpErrorException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:723)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:639)
... 54 more
2023-05-04T12:39:29.256+05:30  WARN 272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: The request failed. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized]

Thanks in advance for you help.
Also suggest whether this is the correct approach to listen the new emails from EWS service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic authentication has been depreciated in Office365 so can't be used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online. You need to implement oauth in your code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth.

For what your trying to do (listen to new email in Office 365) the Graph API would be a better option as EWS is considered legacy and may not be available in the future (the only context in which EWS is needed is OnPrem Exchange). In the Graph you can create a Webhook https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0 or as your just doing pull notifications you could use the delta endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview

Comment: Thanks a lot Glen! I will try to implement the same with Graph API. 
Do you have any code reference where we can check the implementation of graph Api to receive emails in java spring boot application. ?